# Transfer different currencies between wallets

Tags: wallet, coinbase.com

I had SCOTCOIN in a counterwallet.io address and I transferred it to a Coinbase BTC wallet. I wouldn't have thought the transaction would have worked but it did. The amount of BTC in the Coinbase wallet in no way reflects the going exchange rate.

What's gone wrong and can it be fixed?

Comment: coinbase: "we will not be able to return any alt-coin funds accidentally sent to Coinbase-controlled addresses". So you can send one coin specie to another alt-coin address and the coin will simply be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* send one kind of cryptocurrency to another cryptocurrency's wallet. The transaction will complete **but** the coin will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

well perhaps there is nobody in Coinbase who monitors actual price of SCOTCOIN.

In any case, they probably still have the SCOTCOIN so maybe contact them fast before they sell it?

Comment: Thanks fo the suggestion. I'll update with what Coinbase say.

Comment: don't send altcoin to bitcoin-only companies. Sorry for your loss.